# Decompressing an XML in python from an API request

Tags: python, xml, gzip, compression

I am trying to use the API from https://neweden-dev.com/ZKillboard_API in python.

My code works up to this point:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib2
import gzip
import zlib


url = 'https://zkillboard.com/api/kills/characterID/95089021/xml/'
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header('Accept-encoding', 'gzip,deflate')

data = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

After this point, I get very confused.

```
contents = data.read()
f = open("export.xml","w")
f.write(contents)
f.close()
```

Above was my first step. Opening the file made me realize that it was compressed (duh).

So from this point I tried two things:

```
f = open("test.xml.gz", "w")
f.write(data.read())
f.close()
g = gzip.open("test.xml.gz", "rb")
file_content = g.read()
g.close()
```

which gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[filepath]", line 19, in <module>
    file_content = g.read()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\gzip.py", line 254, in read
    self._read(readsize)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\gzip.py", line 312, in _read
    uncompress = self.decompress.decompress(buf)
error: Error -3 while decompressing: invalid distance too far back
```

My next step was to use zlib:

```
x = zlib.decompress(data.read())
```

which gives me the error of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[filepath]", line 15, in <module>
    x = zlib.decompress(data.read())
error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

I know I am missing something super simple here, any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: It should be `f = open("test.xml.gz", "wb")`.

Comment: Yep, there it is. Thank you.